# golang reproducable binary - changing buildId

Tags: go, aws-sdk-go-v2

Currently trying to work out why building twice from same source creates different `buildid` and more specifically different `actionID` part.

I have vendored the dependencies with the following `main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    awsConfig "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
)

func main() {
    awsCfg, err := awsConfig.LoadDefaultConfig(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    _ = awsCfg
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

```bash
go build -o bootstrap -mod=vendor -trimpath -buildvcs=false cmd/main.go
go clean --cache
go build -o bootstrap2 -mod=vendor -trimpath -buildvcs=false cmd/main.go
```

will produce the following difference respectively:

```
4PSJ2COQu-WEdQUCy9GF/bEj2KquhCFU77YWE3s8m/M-Eq01RmuZNuSlF4NvKh/Sw9yCoyvM-OHIpXpdNG5
1B4wdixPXI9YqxSglbgJ/bEj2KquhCFU77YWE3s8m/M-Eq01RmuZNuSlF4NvKh/Sw9yCoyvM-OHIpXpdNG5
```

This is causing updates to a `lambda` function has the produced `hash` from `aws-cdk` differs between builds on `circleci` even if nothing within the actual function has changed. I understand we could pass `ldflags=-buildid=` as a build argument (??) but want to understand what could be causing this change in `actionId`

This change is not consistent and sometimes produces the same `buildId`

```
go version go1.19 darwin/amd64
```

edit:

The following [issue 33772](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33772) states this was resolved when using `-trimpath`